# sorting a range inside an array for counting rather than logically

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Given an array of 10 members, 9 of which will be integers, how do you sort elements with index ranging from 4 to 9?

For example:

Input: `[Input vector,2,8,2084,33,49,42,8,21,37]`

Output:  `[33,49,42,8,21,37]`

`Array.Sort(InputArray,4,6)` produces `[21,33,37,42,49,8]`, which is a logical sort. However, we need this range to be in simple ascending order: `[8,21,33,37,42,49]`

How can we achieve this?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: made edit in question to indicate the language is c#, framework 4.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in your array appears to be getting interpreted as string data. This would explain why 8 comes at the end of the list, rather than at the beginning (since the string "8" does come after the string "21" lexicographically).

To get around this, you can do either of the following things:

1. Convert the portion of the array you would like to sort into an array of some numeric type, e.g., int. This would involve some copying and might not be ideal.
2. Implement a class that implements IComparer where you can define the comparison operation to be used. Basically, you should convert both string operands to the comparison function into numbers, and return the appropriate value depending on the numeric comparison. This is probably what you want.